# Can I apply consistent sample numbers using group_by function in conjunction?

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by, sample

I am trying to select a single value using sample() and apply it to my data where x = 0 using an ifelse statement, but apply this to multiple rows of data relating to a project using group_by() but together it is not producing what I would like. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

`df %>% group_by(project) %>% mutate(VarB = ifelse(VarA == 0, sample(1:5, nrow(df), replace = TRUE), 1))`

What I am getting is sample numbers between 1-5 that vary across all rows of project data when VarA == 0, instead of being consistent across all rows as I'm hoping to achieve by using the group_by() command.

Can anyone guide me in how to amend the code to achieve what I want?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of sample data?

Comment: `sample` is inherently random yet you want a "consistent" result.  That's a contradiction.  Please also provide the expected output based on your sample data.  Also, your title references `x`, but `x` doesn't appear in your sample code.  All in all, I have no idea how to help you.

Comment: I understand that sample is a random number generator, but I would like the random number to be assigned to a project - as it stands, I have several different rows of data for each project and sample is assigning a different number to each row in the data. I just wondered if there was a better way to group_by project to achieve this. I will generate some sample data to show what I mean.

Comment: In the end I just rejigged the way the data was put together to skirt the issue, so resolved from my end. Thanks anyway for the help! :-)